# Display my YouTube channel in an Embed a video wall that supports Annotations

Tags: youtube, video, embed

The scrolling perspective of a Video Wall display for my YouTube Channel video collection would be of great value. Easy access to more than 100 videos.

So I got it working using a Cooliris Express embed code generator. Problem is YouTube video annotations are not enabled in the Cooliris player. This is a big problem. Major loss of functionality. Annotations are very important.  Here is a comparison of the Cooliris Video Wall with a YouTube embed player that supports viewing of video annotation. http://googleplexmath.blogspot.com/p/mathview-video-wall.html

How do I get the Video Wall to show YouTube annotations when a video is selected and then played in the embedded player?

Comment: This question got obsoleted; the Cooliris is dead, the Video Wall is no longer supported, YouTube's APIv2 is dead and YouTube no longer uses the flash player.